# How to filter data from DataTable and assign as itemsSource to DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable

I am using .net 4.0 and VS2010, C# WPF Application
I have datatable filled with data from database. i want to filter it on some critearea and want use that filtered data as DataContext to WPF DataGrid
can any one proved me simple example

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`DataView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) and use that as the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid`.  Add the filter and the sort criteria to the `DataView`.